# HTML Bottom align

Tags: html, css

Im trying to align my image to Top and Bot, but it is not aligning to bottom.
My Code :

```
style='position:absulte;margin-top:-1px;width:80%;height:95%;bottom:10%'
```

(Bottom:10% is not working)
I have tried another solving topics on StackOverflow, none of them worked.

[image: Code do not align the image]

Comment: Start by trying to spell `absolute` correctly.

Comment: @CBroe I did it. The problem was not it. I already answered to it and it is working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution by changing *style*
Previus code :

```
style='position:absulte;margin-top:-1px;width:80%;height:95%;bottom:10%'
```

New code:

```
style='width:900px;height:600px'
```